# How to install Postgres using Chocolatey Nuget when I receive a password complexity error

Tags: powershell-2.0, chocolatey

I'm trying to install postgresql using Chocolatey nuget and I get the following error:

> Write-Error : postgresql did not finish successfully. Boo to the
> chocolatey gods!
>
> [ERROR] Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy
> requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity
> and password history requirements.

This is because the username being set is postgres and the password is Postgres1234 and so I suppose [you aren't allowed your username in your password](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Is there a way to pass in the password as a parameter to the chocolatey installation?
Or alternatively some Powershell magic I can use to alter the password rules while I run the package?

---

Update: my [pull request](http://github.com/ferventcoder/chocolatey-packages/pull/33) to change the password in the PG 8 and 9 packages has been accepted so this issue should go away once that new version of the package is visible via `choco install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've managed to disable the password complexity requirements using:

```
#Postgres cannot install because the password contains the username so
Mkdir c:\temp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
secedit /export /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg
(gc c:\temp\secpol.cfg).replace("PasswordComplexity = 1", "PasswordComplexity = 0") | sc C:\temp\secpol.cfg
secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg c:\temp\secpol.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY 
rm -force c:\temp\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
#then install
cinst postgresql
cinst pgadmin3
```

The secedit calls are a modified version of the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23265181/222163). That answer doesn't save the changes to the secpol file that is added here with `| sc C:\temp\secpol.cfg`

Obviously if you come here and paste this code... you should consider turning complexity back on afterwards.

I'm still interested in a better way of solving this issue...

Comment: So this is prolly easy enough to fix. The package is over at https://github.com/ferventcoder/chocolatey-packages although you could edit the chocolateyInstall.ps1 to change the password and then do a -force install to have a more secure password. Please note that this ability is going away as the rewrite will remove the package on -force and reinstall the same version.