# Can you create an anonymous-access Windows share all from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, share

Windows makes it difficult to create a network share with *anonymous access* (in other words, users who the share-hosting machine **does not know about** can access). The `net share ShareName=C:\DesiredShareSource /GRANT:EVERYONE,FULL` gives access to Everyone, but that does not include anonymous access (e.g. non-domain joined users, WITHOUT prompting credentials).

I know there's a way to do this from a GUI (https://serverfault.com/questions/272409/setting-up-an-anonymous-windows-server-2008-network-share), but is there a way changing security policies and creating anonymous network shares can be done strictly from PowerShell?

**EDIT**

This is what happens when I run the WMI script posted by Ansgar Wiechers. I get an exception but the share mounts successfully:
[image: share mounting with exception]
However, when I try and connect to the share from another box on the same network, I am still prompted for a username and password, as seen below:

[image: still requiring username and password]

Again, I want anonymous access (no username and password) to be set up all from command line.

Here is the exact code I am using in testingAnonShare.ps1, on a Win7 system:

```
$path        = 'C:\Users\<REDACTED>\Desktop\Attempt'
$name        = 'testinganon'
$description = 'share description'

function Get-Trustee($sid) {
  $trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_Trustee').CreateInstance()
  $trustee.SID = ([wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='$sid'").BinaryRepresentation
  return $trustee
}

function New-FullAce($sid) {
  $ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').CreateInstance()
  $ace.AccessMask = 2032127  # full control
  $ace.AceFlags   = 3        # container inherit + object inherit
  $ace.AceType    = 0        # access allowed
  $ace.Trustee    = Get-Trustee $sid
  return $ace
}

$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL         = (New-FullAce 'S-1-1-0'),
                   (New-FullAce 'S-1-5-7')

$wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List
$wmi.Create($path, $name, 0, $null, $description, '', $sd) | Out-Null
```

Comment: `net.exe SHARE ShareName=C:\DesiredShareSource /GRANT:"ANONYMOUS LOGON",FULL` but in place `"ANONYMOUS LOGON"` must be localized string - it will be used in `LookupAccountName` function. however if you grant only ANONYMOUS LOGON" - usual users will no permissions here, so need add everyone too - `/GRANT:Everyone,FULL`

Comment: I still am prompted to enter a password when I do `net SHARE ShareName=C:\DesiredShareSource /GRANT:"ANONYMOUS LOGON",FULL`. Also, it requires me to put a ` before the commas in both GRANT statements. Is there any reason I am still prompted to enter credentials when I access the shares from other boxes?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/126214/how-to-create-network-file-shares-with-no-passwords-in-windows-8/

Comment: @RbMm that's how I started here. I want to do this all from PowerShell.

Comment: Same question. Nobody seems to have a PowerShell approach.

Answer (score 4):

All examples create a share called `test` mapped to a path `D:\test`, granting full access to Anonymous and Everyone.

### Windows Server 2012 R2 and newer

To create a share with `everyone` having `Full` access this is the command

```
New-SmbShare -Name 'test' -path 'D:\test' -FullAccess 'ANONYMOUS LOGON','Everyone'
```

To update an existing share to have the same permission is a little more complicated.  First, assume the share name is `test`.  Here is the code to change it to the same permissions as above.

```
Get-SmbShare -Name test | 
    Set-SmbShare -SecurityDescriptor 'O:BAG:DUD:(A;;FA;;;AN)(A;;FA;;;WD)'
```

To get the SecurityDescriptor string, create a share test like you want it and run the following command.

```
(get-smbshare -Name Test).SecurityDescriptor
```

### Backward compatible (NET SHARE)

This can also be done with `net share`

```
net share test=D:\test /GRANT:"ANONYMOUS LOGON,FULL" /GRANT:"Everyone,FULL"
```

Comment: I believe 'Everyone' does not incorporate anonymous access. Specifically, when the hosting machine does not know about the user trying to access, so it has no means of authenticating that user.

Comment: I don't have New-SmbShare working on PowerShell. Is there a specific version required? Unfortunately I'd like a backwards-compatible solution.

Comment: Per the docs, it was added in Windows Server 2012 R2.  Before this version of windows PowerShell did not technically have a way to do this.  I can check if `net share` can do the same thing.  Give me a bit...

Comment: I've updated the answer with both options.  I removed the guest permissions as the account is usually disabled.

Comment: I am still getting prompted for a username and password with the `net share` command. Is there any reason this might be happening?

Comment: I think why the client is still prompting for a credential is something to be asked [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).  Browsing the few related questions, seem to indicate that the default client authentication settings in windows do not allow anonymous connections, but I did not find an exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [`New-SmbShare`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722.aspx) (Windows Server 2012 or newer) and [`net share`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750728.aspx) you can also use WMI for creating network shares.

```
$path        = 'C:\DesiredShareSource'
$name        = 'sharename'
$description = 'share description'

function Get-Trustee($sid) {
  $trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_Trustee').CreateInstance()
  $trustee.SID = ([wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='$sid'").BinaryRepresentation
  return $trustee
}

function New-FullAce($sid) {
  $ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').CreateInstance()
  $ace.AccessMask = 2032127  # full control
  $ace.AceFlags   = 3        # container inherit + object inherit
  $ace.AceType    = 0        # access allowed
  $ace.Trustee    = Get-Trustee $sid
  return $ace
}

$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL += (New-FullAce 'S-1-1-0').PSObject.BaseObject
$sd.DACL += (New-FullAce 'S-1-5-7').PSObject.BaseObject

$wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List
$wmi.Create($path, $name, 0, $null, $description, '', $sd) | Out-Null
```

`S-1-1-0` and `S-1-5-7` are the [well-known SIDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) of the *Everyone* and *Anonymous* groups respectively.

Appending each ACE separately to the `DACL` property is required to make the code work with PowerShell v2. In more recent version you can assign the ACEs as an array, and you also don't need to unwrap the base object:

```
$sd.DACL = (New-FullAce 'S-1-1-0'), (New-FullAce 'S-1-5-7')
```

To actually enable anonymous access to shares you also need to make three changes to the local security policy ([source](http://nikolar.com/2015/03/10/creating-network-share-with-anonymous-access/)):

1. Start `secpol.msc`.
2. Navigate to *Security Settings → Local Policies → Security Options*.
3. Change the following settings:

   - `Accounts: Guest account status` → `Enabled`
   - `Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users` → `Enabled`
   - `Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously` → *sharename*

Note that I did not have to change the setting `Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares` to enable anonymous access from Windows 7 to an anonymous share on Server 2012 R2, but I did have to add NTFS permissions for the *Everyone* group.

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path 'C:\DesiredShareSource'
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
  'Everyone', 'ReadAndExecute', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
)
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Get-Acl -Path 'C:\DesiredShareSource' -AclObject $acl
```

I'm not aware of a way to make the policy changes with a script. You may be able to cook up something by [wrapping `secedit` in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23265181/1630171), but whenever I had to deal with `secedit` it turned out to be … bothersome, so I wouldn't recommend it. In a domain environment you can deploy local security policy settings via group policies, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me `Exception setting "DACL": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject'."` 

It successfully creates the share, but once again it is non anonymous, as it requires credentials to be accessed by other boxes.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning The code worked just fine when I tested it. Please provide evidence (show your code and the exact error message, preferably in your question).

Comment: I updated the question with the screenshots you requested.

Comment: I used the exact code from your post, changing only the path and name variables.

Comment: The exception goes away, but yet again I am prompted for a username and password when I try and connect to the share from another box's PowerShell. That's the only issue I'm trying to address. Are you really not prompted for credentials when you do a `net use \\boxname\sharename`?