# how can i edit something in gpedit.msc with cmd/batchscript

Tags: powershell, security, cmd, group-policy

My main problem is I am facing the problem ->  [image]

when i am trying to execute my exe file (which i written and compiled in C using GCC). I have found the solution and the solution is to change some of the settings under gpedit.msc

```
run -> gpedit.msc -> computer configuration -> windows settings -> security settings -> 
local policies -> security options
```

there are multiple files. I just want to edit files whose name starts with "User Account Control: "

Either i want to enable or disable them. How can i do that programatically using cmd/batch script?

till now i have found secdit but that does not edit the values. link -> [scroll down little bit and you will find secedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/administer-security-policy-settings). I also used resource monitor to observe registry changes when i disable something according to this link -> [Use Process Monitor to Find Registry Changes](https://www.maketecheasier.com/registry-values-for-group-policy-settings-windows/). But nothing shows up. Somewhere in the internet i also found that security policies are not always associated with registry values. But i forgot to save the link. I also found this stackoverflow article [Modify Local Security Policy using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260656/modify-local-security-policy-using-powershell)
. But i can't understand anything as i know nothing about powershell programming and secedit or "how to edit database". Please provide some juicy resources to learn about editing security policies.

For your information i am building my program.exe in my local computer (house pc) and transferring the generated exe in "Amazon EC2 instance". If you say compile the program in "Amazon EC2" RDP i will say that i dont need to do that because my program.exe is running fine in "Amazon EC2" if i disable or enable some of the "User Account Control: " settings

Comment: You can probably achieve this using powershell: https://serverfault.com/questions/848388/how-to-edit-local-group-policy-with-a-script

Comment: of no use because it is not neccessary that every security policy must link with registry value. In my case none of the security policy i want to edit is linked with registry value.

Comment: "none of the security policy i want to edit is linked with registry value" i said this because when i tried to examine the registry value change on changing security policy through resource monitor i found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything I wanted to know -> [Registrykey Values Associated with local policies](http://woshub.com/user-account-control-slider-and-group-policy-settings/) and thanks to -> [Grzegorz Ochlik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5720797/grzegorz-ochlik).